# Using Session for preventing round trip requests

Tags: asp.net, caching, session

I have a Telerik Menu in usercontrol that located in aspx page, I need to generate menu based on logged in user.

So I need to bind datasource to the menu.
My web site gonna have more than 1000 users per day. 
For preventing round trip requests, I generate the menu from session.
I use InProc session for that purpose and I keep the Sql Data in session.

The session object size for menu is about 40 bytes. So (1000 users) * (40 bytes ) =about 40K server's memory. 
I don't have any other server for using StateServer Session. 
And also I am going to use session for some other purposes too.

Is there any better solution for that cause the performance plays a key role for my scenario.
Or already I've chosen the best solution ?

Comment: 1) 1000 user per day or 1000 simultaneous users? 2) So far I understand the menu is custom per user you may have 1000 different menus, isn't it?

Comment: If memory usage and request processing time weren't critically important I'd look at implementing a SiteMapProvider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.aspx). If you could cache the user data in there then the entire sites structure could be user specific. This may help when you need to implement other navigation controls and security restrictions.

Comment: yeah  1000 simultaneous users and the menu is custom per user.

Comment: My main concern in memory usage and request processing time. So that's the reason I shared my scenario with you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you should have any problem doing it this way, but you may be interested in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139207/managing-user-specific-parameters/4139369#4139369).

Generally speaking, the session is a good place to cache data which:

1. Is relatively small,
2. Is expensive to obtain, and
3. Doesn't need to be used outside a given user's session

It sounds like you match at least the first two requirements above.

One project I worked on had a need similar to the one you're describing, but many users would end up with the exact same menu, and the generation of the menu itself was expensive, so I divided the problem into pieces, like this:

- The user's PersonId is stored on the session.
- A MenuKeyRepository would get a list of the IDs of the menu item keys that need to appear for a given person ID, and return this list as a "MenuKey".
- A MenuRepository would generate the actual menu based on a given MenuKey.

These two repositories used a sliding memory cache, so that in most cases both the menu key and the menu itself would already be constructed. If a new user logs in, but is supposed to see the same menu items as some other recent user, the first repository needs to construct their menu key, but the actual menu is already cached.

I don't know if this approach would make sense for you, but there it is, for what it's worth.

Comment: Each user has multiple roles.And also each page has multiple roles too. I match the logged in user's roles with page's roles and generate the custom menu for that user. In many cases they gonna have the same menu. But I don't know when to put the repetitive custom menu in to the cache.

Comment: @arlen: So if you often have large groups of users with the same set of roles, and if the menu is significantly larger or more expensive to generate than the list of roles, you might make a composite key out of the user's role IDs. Then anybody who has the same set of roles could reuse the same generated menu item. Does that make sense?

Comment: @arlen: Precisely. But, like I said, only if you expect a lot of your users to have the same roles. If 50% of your users have roles(1,2), for example, this approach will probably give you better performance, because you won't have to go matching roles 1 and 2 to every page every time a new user logs in.

Comment: @arlen: I guess the logic would be more like `var menu = (Menu)Cache.Get(rolesString); if(menu == null) Cache.Set(rolesString, menu = GenerateMenu(roles));`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior : You mean If user1=roles(1,2,3) and user2=roles(1,2,3,4) - then I generate composite key for keyUser1=123 and for keyUser2=1234 so if keyUser1=keyUser2 retrieve the menu from cache. otherwise generate the new menu and put the new one in cache Cache.Insert(keyUser2, "MenuItems"). So In that case the cache will suck up the server's memory. cause I am gonna have combination of roles. So Instead of session now I have cache ... so what's a good point of doing that ? I call your method "Implement InProc Session using Cache"

Comment: @arlen: Like I said before, this approach only makes sense if multiple concurrent users are likely to have the same set of roles. In that case, it allows you to reuse the menu object between the users' sessions. If your 1000 concurrent users have 1000 different combinations of roles, this basically becomes a "session using cache" like you say. Likewise, if the menu is small (40 bytes is small in my book) and cheap to build (database roundtrips are not cheap) then you might as well rebuild the menu for each user and store it on the session like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a pretty good solution already, assuming that session timeouts are not an issue.

Comment: What's the best timeout value for session in this scenario?

Comment: That seems like a hardware specific question arlen